# can't access soft deleted file in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

im trying to restore soft deleted file in laravel public folder,
heres my code on delete method :

```
  $submissions = Submission::find((int)$id);
  $submissionPath = public_path().'/'.$submissions->submission_path;
  if(File::exists($submissionPath)){
    // delete file :
    File::delete(public_path($submissionPath));

    // delete in database :
    $submissions->delete();
    return ResponseFormatter::success(
      $submissions
      , 'Submission successfully deleted');
  }else{
    return ResponseFormatter::error(null, 'file not found', 404);
  }
```

im curently know how to restore soft deleted field on database, but im strugling alot with the file on storage.
is anyone know how to make restore() function? especially for soft deleted FILE

Comment: I don't think you can soft-delete an actual file on the system. It's either deleted, or it's not. A soft_deleted database entry is just another column in the database.

Comment: soft delete is not meant for deleting actual file. You should not delete the file when you are trying to soft delete it

Comment: firstly idk that the file will also be soft deleted. the problem that i got here i cant link to file that have been soft-deleted, thats why i wanna restore it. but dint have have any clue bout that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soft deletes only apply to database records. When a model uses the SoftDeletes trait, it will use the deleted_at column to determine whether or not a record is deleted. There is no concept of soft-deleting a file. You could create your own by wiring up your deletion code to move the file to a separate folder so it can be restored when the record is restored.